# How to reverse comma separated string in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use a formula in MS Excel to reverse a comma separated sting in row? The number of values are not always same so some rows have 3, 4 and some only one element.

So the output looks like following image

[image]

Comment: Can you show more examples? What would `Apple,Orange,Grape` return? Would it be `Grape,Orange,Apple` or `eparG,egnarO,elppA`?

Comment: Can you use macros?

Comment: try this :`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(” “,A1))&” “&LEFT(A1,FIND(” “,A1)-1)`

Comment: @i_th that would work: 1 if there were only two words, 2 there were a space dividing them, neither is true in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sloppy UDF solution:

```
Function REVERSESTRING(original As Range, delim As String)

    Dim i As Long, reversed As String, arr As Variant

    arr = Split(original.Value, delim)

    For i = UBound(arr) To 0 Step -1
        reversed = reversed & arr(i) & ","
    Next i

    REVERSESTRING = Left(reversed, Len(reversed) - 1)

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Hi but I am getting `#NAME? ` in return

Comment: @MonaCoder did you put the code in a module?  If you put it in `ThisWorkbook` or the worksheet code sheet then it will not be found.  You need to put the code in a module attached to the workbook.

Comment: I actually put the code in Both `Sheet1` and `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks got it now after adding to the Module

Answer (score 6):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use This array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1)-ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1)))*99+1,99)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If one does not have Office 365 Excel then vba will probably be the only choice.

[image]

Comment: @dwirony shhhhhhh, don't let my secret out.  I sold my soul to the StackDevil a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting `#NAME?` in return

Comment: @MonaCoder then you are not using Office 365 Excel and will need to use the vba code that was provided by dwirony.

Comment: @ScottCraner WHAT IN THE WORLD. I quit excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Sorry to hijack this.. What happened to Dennis (Jeeped). I am asking you as I believe he is a good friend of yours?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am not sure.  I have not heard from him since he hit 100k.  Shortly after hitting 100k he got put in the penalty box for some harsh comments, and never came back.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Agreed

Answer (score -1):

A pure **single-cell formula** works in *Excel 365*; with that version there is no need for special array calculation entry, VBscripts, or helper columns:

[image: Three-column excel table, showing a comma-separated list being reversed]

---

### Procedure

Make the following table in Excel:
[image]

1. Add column headings
2. Select headings, and press the *Table* icon on the *Insert* ribbon tab
3. Copy formula 1 & 2 below into the appropriate columns

   ```swift
   Original |  #  |  Reversed
   ---------+-----+-----------
            | {1} |       {2}
   ```
4. Place the string you would like to reverse in the first column.

---

### Details and customization

#### 'Original' column

*(holds the delimited string value you wish to process)*

Place your source data in this column *(as seen in the example images)*

#### '#' column

*(counts number of items in delimited cell)*

Note: *(this column is **completely optional**; it simply shows the number of items in the original column)*

{1} <- replace with formula #1:

```swift
=LET(
    existingDelimiter, ","
    , originalValue,   [@[Original]]
    , SUM(
        LEN(originalValue) 
        - LEN(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                originalValue
                , existingDelimiter
                , ""
            )
        )
    )
    +1
)
```

(Note: If your list uses a delimiter *other than a comma* or if the first column of your table will have a different name, edit the above as appropriate using the same instructions given for *formula #2* below.)

#### 'Reversed' column

*(reverses order of delimited items in list; optionally changes delimiter)*

{2} <- replace with formula #2:

```swift
=LET(
    existingDelimiter, ","
    , newDelimiter,    ","
    , originalValue,   [@[Original]]
    , SUBSTITUTE(
        ARRAYTOTEXT(
            LET(
                list,
                    IFERROR(
                        FILTERXML(
                            "<t><s>"
                                & SUBSTITUTE(
                                    originalValue
                                    ,existingDelimiter
                                    ,"</s><s>"
                                )
                                & "</s></t>"
                            , "//s"
                        )
                        ,""
                    )
                ,SORTBY(
                    list,
                    SEQUENCE(
                        ROWS(list)
                        ,1
                        ,ROWS(list)
                        ,-1
                    )
                )
            )
            ,0
        )
        , ", "
        , newDelimiter
    )
)
```

1. Adjust the formula for what you are trying to accomplish by changing the values for `existingDelimiter`, `newDelimiter`, and `originalValue`, as necessary.

   A. To reverse a comma-separated string, use the formula as written:

   ```swift
      existingDelimiter, ","
      , newDelimiter,    ","
   ```

   1. Example:
      [image: Three-column excel table, showing a comma-separated list being reversed]

   B. To reverse DNS names, replace the comma with a period in the definitions for `existingDelimiter` and `newDelimiter`:

   ```swift
      existingDelimiter, "."
      , newDelimiter,    "."
   ```

   1. This can be very useful for [reverse DNS names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) (aka Java class names / [Universal Type Indicators (UTIs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) / etc.)
   2. Example:
      [image: Three-column excel table, showing a period-separated list being reversed]
2. Replace "Original" in `[@[Original]]` with the name of your first column, if different.

   A. If using just a single cell for input instead of a table column, replace `[@[Original]]` with the reference to that cell (e.g. `B2`):

   ```swift
     , originalValue,   B2
   ```

   1. Example:

      [image: two spreadsheet cells, the first showing the list 'a,b,c,d' and the second showing the list 'd,c,b,a']

###### Explaination of the "Reversed" column formula:

1. By manually converting to XML, we can use the *FilterXML* function, which converts the data to an *array*.
2. Having the data in an *array* allows the use of the *SortBy* function.
3. *SortBy* reverses the *array* by using a helper *array* created with the *Sequence* function.
4. Finally, the *ArrayToText* functions converts this (now reverse-ordered) *array* back to a text string that will fit in a single spreadsheet cell.

This is what allows us not to need a loop, helper columns, or VBScript.

---

##### Bonus column

To extract a specific term from a list, use the following formula in another table column:

1. (Change the number in *termNumber* to the desired value):

   ```swift
   =LET(
       existingDelimiter, ","
       , originalValue,   [@[Original]]
       , termNumber,      "[2]"
       , IFERROR(
           FILTERXML(
               "<t><s>"
           & SUBSTITUTE(
               originalValue
               , existingDelimiter
               , "</s><s>"
           )
           & "</s></t>"
           , "//s"
               & termNumber
           )
           , ""
       )
   )
   ```
2. Example:

   [image: Three-column excel table (same as above), showing a comma-separated list being reversed, but with a fourth column added that shows the second part of the value in the first column]

---

#### Other notes

Needed:

- *Excel 365* (for at least *FilterXML* and *Let* functions, and *dynamic arrays*) (*)

  - It might work with other versions but I have not tested those. Please note in the comments if you notice other or future versions (e.g. *Excel 2022*)  work with this.

*Not* needed:

- dynamic array entry
- VBscript
- macro-enabled files

(*) This can be done *without* the *Let* function, but using *Let* allows the calculation to be edited / repurposed with less chance for user error.

Note: When the *Lambda* function is released *(hopefully later in 2021)* then this all can be wrapped up in a named worksheet function

**Bonus**: to edit more complex Excel formulas with code highlighting *(and other features such as auto-intents and folding)*, try a text editor with [Swift](https://swift.org/) programming language support. Examples:

1. [VSCode editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) *(free; cross-platform)*

   - Until there is an Excel-specific extension available, install a *Swift* VSCode extension such as this: [Swift language VSCode extension](http://Name:%20Swift%20Language%20Id:%20kasik96.swift%20Description:%20Swift%20language%20support%20for%20VS%20Code%20Version:%200.2.0%20Publisher:%20Martin%20Kase%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kasik96.swift) (it seems to work quite well to provide code highlighting and folding)
2. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) *(free; Windows-only)*

   - Select "Swift" from the "Language" menu

---

Inspired by *(apologies if I've forgotten someone)*:

- https://www.howtoexcel.org/tutorials/split-text-by-delimiter/
- https://www.sumproduct.com/news/article/have-you-got-what-it-text-introducing-arraytotext-and-valuetotext
- https://exceljet.net/formula/reverse-a-list-or-range